# How can I Identify the DIv which got clicked in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know where the click event happens in my document, i Have some divs , and when i press cntrl key and click on them some events will occur, i just need to know how to identify the divs which got clicked, is it possible to generalize them in document.click fn Like what i have tried.
Here is a sample of what i have tried

HTML

```
<div class="DivOne">Div1</div>
<div class="DivTwo">Div2</div>
<div class="DivThree">Div3</div>
```

Jquery

```
   $(document).bind("click", function (e) {
    if (e.which == '17') {
        alert(e.parent);//I need to know Whether Click happens on divOne or Two or on No Mans Land
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: A better way is to have a common class name assigned to the divs and bind to that rather than binding a click to document itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `e.target` along with `.is()` function to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
   $(document).bind("click", function (e) {
     if($(e.target).is('.DivOne')){
       alert('Div one has been clicked..!')
     }
   });
```

Comment: Hey brother thanks for ur reply , but this fiddle isnt working , can u check this http://jsfiddle.net/rG7G3/

Comment: @ama: it doesn't work because a click event doesn't have a key associated to it, so `e.which` will never have hat value. If you look carefully then you see the solution in this answer doesn't use `e.which` at all. Maybe read again how `e.which` Works?

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah i just checked it now, it is returning a value 1 while we making a click. But i thought that it would display `undefined`

Comment: The documentation actually mentions that it has the value 1, 2 or 3, depending on which button was pressed.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks brother, I checked it  .which is not working but e.ctrlKey is working

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").click(function (e) {
    var classOfDiv = this.className;
    // do stuff depending on what class
});
```

Comment: how about this.HTMLElement ?

Comment: What's wrong with event delegation like the op uses?

Comment: This is also working fine for me , But i need it in document , Thank You brother

Comment: @FelixKling now that i think about it, nothing is wrong with it. thank you for making me think more

Answer (score 0):

You can select classes, or ids like so

```
$("#DivOne").click(function (e) {
if (e.which == '17') {
    alert(e.parent);//I need to know Whether Click happens on divOne or Two or on No Mans Land
    }
});
```

or a class like

```
$(".DivOne").click(function (e) {
if (e.which == '17') {
    alert(e.parent);//I need to know Whether Click happens on divOne or Two or on No Mans Land
    }
});
```

Alternately you can loop through all divs on the page and test for a click

```
$("div").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var divClass = $(this).attr('class');
        alert("You clicked on " + divClass);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhjHe/)**